# is there a way to find the money made from a ad in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, ads

Lets say a user has watched an ad i would like to change the reward dependant on how much money i made from the ad. i don't want to use ecpm because that is a average. I want the money from a specific ad.the code i am using the default unity ad code from the tutorial. here it is

```
    const string myPlacementId = "rewardedVideo";
    public bool testMode = true;
    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.AddListener(this);
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            ShowRewardedVideo();
        }
    }
    public void ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady(myPlacementId))
        {
            Advertisement.Show(myPlacementId);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Rewarded video is not ready at the moment! Please try again later!");
        }
    }
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            print("finishedAd");
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
        {
            print("skip");
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance.